# Highchart show legend items on drilldown chart

Tags: jquery, highcharts

For my project we use the HighChart jquery plug-in. At the examples we found an drilldown chart for an pie and an column chart.  But when using the drilldown: the legend is wrong. Here is my code:

```
$('#container').highcharts({
    chart: {
        type: 'column'
    },
    credits: {
        enabled: false
    },          
    title: {
        text: 'Drilldown wagenparkinstroom'
    },
    xAxis: {
        type: 'category'
    },
    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: "aantal auto's"
        }
    },
    legend: {
        enabled: true
    },

    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            borderWidth: 0,
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
            }
        }
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Liters',
        colorByPoint: true,
        data: [{
            name: 'Q1',
            y: 55,
            drilldown: 'q1',
        }, {
            name: 'Q2',
            y: 17,
            drilldown: 'q2'
        }, {
            name: 'Q3',
            y: 16,
            drilldown: 'q3'
        }, {
            name: 'Q4',
            y: 10,
            drilldown: 'q4'
        }]
    }],
    drilldown: {
        series: [{
            id: 'q1',
            name: 'Q1',
            data: [
                ['Audi', 6],
                ['Volvo', 8],
                ['Volkswagen', 11],
                ['BMW', 7],
                ['Ford', 7],
                ['Renault', 6],
                ['Peugeot', 4],
                ['Mercedes-Benz', 1],
                ['Skoda', 2],
                ['Opel', 3]
            ]
        },{
            id: 'q2',
            name: 'Q2',
            data: [
                ['Audi', 3],
                ['Volvo', 1],
                ['Volkswagen', 0],
                ['BMW', 2],
                ['Ford', 3],
                ['Renault', 2],
                ['Peugeot', 1],
                ['Mercedes-Benz', 4],
                ['Skoda', 0],
                ['Opel', 1]
            ]
        },{
            id: 'q3',
            name: 'Q3',
            data: [
                ['Audi', 5],
                ['Volvo', 4],
                ['Volkswagen', 2],
                ['BMW', 1],
                ['Ford', 1],
                ['Renault', 1],
                ['Peugeot', 1],
                ['Mercedes-Benz', 0],
                ['Skoda', 1],
                ['Opel', 0]
            ]
        },{
            id: 'q4',
            name: 'Q4',
            data: [
                ['Audi', 1],
                ['Volvo', 2],
                ['Volkswagen', 0],
                ['BMW', 3],
                ['Ford', 1],
                ['Renault', 2],
                ['Peugeot', 0],
                ['Mercedes-Benz', 0],
                ['Skoda', 1],
                ['Opel', 0]
            ]
        }]
    }
});
```

**Produces:**

[image]

As you see: the legend does not match the bars. It here an solution for this to make my legend matches the bars? Thanks!

--- EDIT ---
Already tried this. But the bars stay empty:

```
series: [{
        name: 'Q1',
        y: 55,
        drilldown: 'q1',
    }, {
        name: 'Q2',
        y: 17,
        drilldown: 'q2'
    }, {
        name: 'Q3',
        y: 16,
        drilldown: 'q3'
    }, {
        name: 'Q4',
        y: 10,
        drilldown: 'q4'
}],
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the drilldown, you have single serie, but coloured only points. The legend displays series not points, so as a result you have only single item.

Comment: Thats right, but i'am not in the drilldown yet so i ike to see all the parts. Do you know how to do that?

Comment: In case when you have single serie, you always will have single item. Try to use 5 series (each serie for each point).

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Already tried that (view my edit). Did i do something wrong?

Comment: I think this is example which Sebastian was referring: http://jsfiddle.net/yURKz/ Each of points is different series, and each series contains data points.

Comment: Nice! That is what i searched for! Thanks!